# Why parent.frame(5)?

Tags: r, environment

Can anyone help me counting the frames?
I have a shortcut to `load` function:

```
loa=function(x,dir='./dados/') { 
      if(right(dir,1) != '/') dir=paste0(dir,'/')
      tryCatch(load(paste0(dir,gsub('\"','',deparse(substitute(x))),'.rda'),envir = parent.frame(1))
       ,error= function(e) print(e)
       ,warning= function(e)
         load(paste0(dir,x,'.rda'),envir = parent.frame(5))
       )
}
```

In it, it is possible to put variable name without quotes, with quotes or a variable with the name. E.g., `loa(VALE3)` or `loa('VALE3')` or `var_name='VALE3'; loa(var_name)` works.
To make it work, I had to put `parent.frame(5)` - from 1 to 4 did not work. I can count `.GlobalEnv`, `loa` frame, `tryCatch` frame, even `warning`frame.
What are the other frames?

P.S.

```
right=function(x, n)  
   if(n>0) substr(x, (nchar(x)-n+1), nchar(x)) else substr(x, 1, (nchar(x)+n))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using relative parent frames, it's much more direct to just capture the frame as the start of the function then pass that directly. (You don't have control over how many frames `tryCatch` created when it runs).

And while I think allowing either a string or a symbol name is really just a dangerous mess, R does allow it. You can inspect the type of the promise passed to the function and deparse it if it's not a string. It's would be better to have two different parameters. One if you want to pass a symbol, and a different one if you want to pass a character.

```
loa <- function(x, dir='./dados/') { 
      toenv <- parent.frame()
      xn <- substitute(x)
      if (!is.character(xn)) xn <- deparse(xn)
      if (right(dir,1) != '/') dir <- paste0(dir, '/')
      path <- paste0(dir,gsub('\"', '', xn), '.rda')
      tryCatch(load(path, envir = toenv), 
          error = function(e) print(e)
      )
}
```

Comment: Nice solution saving `parent.frame`. But it does not work when `var_name='VALE3'; loa(var_name)`.

Comment: @xm1 Well this why I don't suggest you do this. You want `loa(VALE3)` and `loa("VALE3")` and `VALE3<-"VALE2"; loa(VALE3)` to work? How does R tell the different between the first and last. The first you are treating like a symbol, the second you are treading like a variable that needs evaluation. Functions like `library()` in R that take both quotes and no-quotes don't allow variables for this reason.

Comment: When it does not find 'var_name', it tries its value. You have a point.